# Entities and Mappings in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm trying to learn Doctrine2, and am having some trouble wrapping my brain around Entities and Mappings, and how to pull data from the db.

If I understand correctly, an Entity would be created for data in my db, like a User or a Product.

That's where I'm getting hung up though.  I have a simple database with tables like User and such.  Do I need to create an Entity called "User"?   And does that entity pull data from the User table, and then I get data from the User entity?

Can someone provide me a code example of how I would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entities are regular PHP classes... First u have to create ur table, then u create your entity. Properties of class should be private with setters and getters and usually with same names as field in table. When U want to put new record in DB, u must make instance of class u want and set values then persist and flush the entity manager. Example code:

```
    <?php

namespace Entity;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users")
 */
class User {

    /** @Id 
     *  @Column(type="integer")
     *  */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $username;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $password;

    /** @Column(type="boolean") */
    private $active;

    public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
    return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username) {
    $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
    return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
    $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getActive() {
    return $this->active;
    }

    public function setActive($active) {
    $this->active = $active;
    }

}
```

and when u want to put a new record:

```
$user = new Entity\User();
$user->setName('users name');
$user->setPassword('password');
$entityManager->persist($user); // put that entity in queue;
$entityManager->flush(); // execute all pending entities
```

If u want to get existing record

```
$found = $entityManager->find('className', $id); // search by id

or $entityManager->getRepository('className')->findOneBy(array('field', 'value'));
```